# Google maps place markers

Tags: html, google-maps, google-api

Here is my current code: http://virtual.weltec.ac.nz/s13/Site/fireservice.html

This page loads an embedded google map with two markers and traces the route between them when a button is pressed.

My question is this: I am after some code where I can reposition the markers via a simple function. Preferably with the names of the two new places or if not with this then with the coordinates.

Can I please have some help with this?

thanks

EDIT

I have created this function:

```
function setnewMarker(){
doStart(-41,174);
doEnd(-43,182);
```

}

Yet it does not work. Can I please have some help to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```js
var newPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(1, 0); 
marker.setPosition(position);
```

Comment: I tried that, yet I think my ode is a bit different. Can you please have a look at my code to see the relevant code that will work in my page? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the _relevant_ part of your code to your question (using the "edit" link below the question). You seem to have copied your javascript code from somewhere else and expecting the SO users to adapt it to your requirements. You have to show that _you_ put some effort in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the previous `marker` and create a new one at the new location.
To [delete a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#RemovingOverlays), you simply call `marker.setMap(null);`, where `marker` is the name of your marker.

Comment: Technically, this isn't a **delete**; it simply disconnects the `Marker` from the map and turns off the display. The `Marker` still exists after `marker.setMap( null )`.